# I am having trouble with making a string of arrays of chars to print to screen in the Unity engine

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, char, screen

I am having trouble with making a string of arrays of chars to print to screen in the Unity engine.

Here is the code

```
{
    public string[] wordGoDownString = new string[12];   

    public void Start()
    {
        char[] chwordGoDownString = wordGoDownString.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char ch in wordGoDownString)
        {

        }
        //char[]wordGoDownString[0] = 'O';
        //char[]wordGoDownString[1] = 'U';
        //char[]wordGoDownString[2] = 'R';
        //char[]wordGoDownString[3] = " ";
        //char[]wordGoDownString[4] = 'P';
        //char[]wordGoDownString[5] = 'R';
        //
        //Print.ToScreen(chars);
        //Print.ToScreen(' ');

        //wordGoDownString[6] = 
        //wordGoDownString[7] = 
        //wordGoDownString[8] = 
        //wordGoDownString[9] = 
        //wordGoDownString[10] =
        //wordGoDownString[11] =
    }
}
   
//     [SerializeField] private string thatString = "b";
//     string yellTheString;
// 
//     public void Start()
//     {
//         foreach (char chars in thatString)
//         {
//             char higherChars = char.ToUpper(chars);
//             yellTheString += higherChars;
//         }
//         Print.ToScreen(yellTheString);
//     }
//     // YellTheString
// }

//SerializeField] private char charLettersDown1 = 'O';
//
//rivate char string [] thatString = new string[12]; 
//
//ublic void Start()
//
//thatString[0] = 'O';
//thatString[1] = 'U';
//thatString[2] = 'R';
//thatString[3] = ' ';
//thatString[4] = 'P';
//thatString[5] = 'R';
//thatString[6] = 'I';
//thatString[7] = 'N';
//thatString[8] = 'C';
//thatString[9] = 'E';
//thatString[10] = 'S';
//thatString[11] = 'S';
//
//
//
/// Borrowing this from the school's code documents.
//
//     

//SerializeField] private char charLettersDown1 = 'O';
//
//rivate char string [] thatString = new string[12]; 
//
//ublic void Start()
//
//thatString[0] = 'O';
//thatString[1] = 'U';
//thatString[2] = 'R';
//thatString[3] = ' ';
//thatString[4] = 'P';
//thatString[5] = 'R';
//thatString[6] = 'I';
//thatString[7] = 'N';
//thatString[8] = 'C';
//thatString[9] = 'E';
//thatString[10] = 'S';
//thatString[11] = 'S';
//
//
//
/// Borrowing this from the school's code documents.
//
//

//}
```

(https://pastebin.com/gEJT2uXc)

Comment: Don't post link to code. Rather paste the code here.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Also this is **NOT `C++`** either! Your code is clearly `c#` ... Also just because you use a certain IDE doesn't mean your question is about that IDE in specific ... You should use `unity3d` though since that is the main framework/API you are using here ...

Comment: Most of your code is commented out ..  so what exactly are you trying to do since currently your code does nothing at all ... Instead of assigning multiple chars ... Why not use a string `string x = "OUR PRICESS";` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you would want to have a banner that goes on one char at a time so something like

```
public float delayPerChar = 1f;
public float delayBetweenWords = 1f;

public string[] wordGoDownString = new string[12];  

private string currentWord;
private int currentWordIndex;
private int currentCharIndex; 

private float timer;

private string currentPrint;

private void Update ()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    // Is currentWord null or whitespace?
    if(string.NullOrWhiteSpace(currentWord))
    {
        // If that's the case we are currently between two words
        // Has the delays exceeded?
        if(timer >= delayBetweenWords)
        {
            // If so pick the next word from the list with wrap around at the end
            currentWordIndex = (currentWordIndex + 1) % wordGoDownString.Length;
            currentWord = wordGoDownString[currentWordIndex];

            // Reset the chat index
            currentCharIndex = 0;
            // Reset the timer
            timer = 0f;
            // Reset the current Print 
            currentPrint = "";

            // print the first char of the current word
            currentPrint += currentWorld[currentCharIndex];
            Print.PrintToScreen(currentPrint);
            // Rest if the word is handled in the else case
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Go to the next char 
        currentCharIndex += 1;

        currentPrint += currentWord [currentCharIndex];

        // reset timer to wait for next char
        timer = 0f;

        // Is this the last in the current word?
        if(currentCharIndex => currentWord.Length - 1)
        {
            // reset currentWord in order to go to next word
            currentWord = null;
        }       
    }
}
```

---

A little bit easier this would be using [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)!

Basically the same code as above as Coroutine could look like

```
// Yes, if you make Start return IEnumerator then Unity automatically runs it as Coroutine
private IEnumerator Start ()
{
    // This is OK in Coroutines as long as you yield somewhere inside
    while(true)
    {
        // Simply iterate the words
        foreach(var currentWord in wordGoDownString)
        {
            // For each word start with an empty print
            var currentPrint = "";
            
            // Simply iterate the chars
            foreach(var currentChar in currentWord.ToCharArray())
            {
                // Append the char and print
                currentPrint += currentChar;
                Print.PrintToScreen(currentPrint);

                // Then wait for the delay
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (delayPerChar);
            }

            // after each word wait for the other delay
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayBetweenWords);
        }
    }
}
```